# Cisco 831 VLAN config

Tags: vlan

I'm looking for a simple, fast way to configure a Cisco 831 router to
do VLAN untagging.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
    PORT 1   (E0)  VLAN 1,2,3,4 tagged
    PORT 2-4 (E0)  VLAN 2,3,4 untagged
    PORT     (E1)  VLAN 1 untagged
```

All other features should be off. RTFM pointers welcome. I'm a Cisco newbie.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Feature Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/by-feature.jsp) at Cisco, and choose the IEEE 802.1Q VLAN Trunking feature (tagging a vlan on an interface is trunking), you'll see that it isn't supported on the 831.  So neither would untagging.